# Time Range in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Im was trying to get the LogIn and LogOut with time of the employee BreakIn and BreakOut.

```
select FirstName, LastName,convert(char(10),dtdate,101) as [LOGDATE] 
,min(convert(char(10),dtdate,108)) as TIMEIN
,max(convert(char(10),dtdate,108)) as TIMEOUT
from TransactionLogs


8:00 In
12:00 Break Out
1:00 Break In
5:00 Out


Sample Output:

FirstName LastName In       Break Out   Break In    Out
Jaime      Craig   8:00AM   12:00PM     1:00PM      5:00PM
```

thanks! :)

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: Some sample data and an exact desired result would help. Your current query couldn't give a result even similar to your sample since it includes for example first name/last name.

Comment: I believe he just has timetamps of log in and log-out dates and he's trying to find out what were the times when the employee logged in the "building", then logged out for lunch, the time he got back in and the time he left home. His issue? **Can't find someone to do it for him**.
***(this is just an assumption)***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @TransactionLogs TABLE
(
    FirstName varchar(50),
    LastName varchar(50),
    dtdate DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @TransactionLogs
( FirstName, LastName, dtdate )
VALUES
( 'Fred', 'Nerfherder', '07/01/2014 08:00:00' ),
( 'Fred', 'Nerfherder', '07/01/2014 12:00:00' ),
( 'Fred', 'Nerfherder', '07/01/2014 13:00:00' ),
( 'Fred', 'Nerfherder', '07/01/2014 18:00:00' ),
( 'Fred', 'Nerfherder', '07/02/2014 07:30:00' ),
( 'Fred', 'Nerfherder', '07/02/2014 12:00:00' ),
( 'Fred', 'Nerfherder', '07/02/2014 13:00:00' ),
( 'Fred', 'Nerfherder', '07/02/2014 17:00:00' ),
( 'Jaime', 'Craig', '07/01/2014 08:00:00' ),
( 'Jaime', 'Craig', '07/01/2014 12:00:00' ),
( 'Jaime', 'Craig', '07/01/2014 13:00:00' ),
( 'Jaime', 'Craig', '07/01/2014 17:00:00' ),
( 'Janet', 'Weiss', '07/01/2014 08:00:00' ),
( 'Janet', 'Weiss', '07/01/2014 17:00:00' ),
( 'Janet', 'Weiss', '07/02/2014 08:00:00' ),
( 'Janet', 'Weiss', '07/02/2014 12:30:00' ),
( 'Janet', 'Weiss', '07/02/2014 14:00:00' ),
( 'Janet', 'Weiss', '07/02/2014 16:30:00' );

SELECT
    t.FirstName,
    t.LastName,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t.Rank = 1 THEN CONVERT(CHAR(10), t.dtdate, 101) END) AS LogDate,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t.Rank = 1 THEN CONVERT(CHAR(10), t.dtdate, 108) END) AS TimeIn,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t.MaxRank = 4 AND t.Rank = 2 THEN CONVERT(CHAR(10), t.dtdate, 108) END) AS BreakOut,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t.MaxRank = 4 AND t.Rank = 3 THEN CONVERT(CHAR(10), t.dtdate, 108) END) AS BreakIn,
    MAX(CASE WHEN (t.MaxRank = 4 AND t.Rank = 4) OR (t.MaxRank = 2 AND t.Rank = 2) THEN CONVERT(CHAR(10), t.dtdate, 108) END) AS TimeOut
FROM
(
    SELECT t.*,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY FirstName, LastName, DATEPART(MONTH, dtdate), DATEPART(DAY, dtdate), DATEPART(YEAR, dtdate) ORDER BY dtdate) as Rank,
        d.MaxRank
    FROM @TransactionLogs t
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS MaxRank
        FROM @TransactionLogs d
        WHERE d.FirstName = t.FirstName
            AND d.LastName = t.LastName
            AND DATEPART(MONTH, d.dtdate) = DATEPART(MONTH, t.dtdate)
            AND DATEPART(DAY, d.dtdate) = DATEPART(DAY, t.dtdate)
            AND DATEPART(YEAR, d.dtdate) = DATEPART(YEAR, t.dtdate)
    ) d
) t
GROUP BY t.FirstName, t.LastName, DATEPART(MONTH, t.dtdate), DATEPART(DAY, t.dtdate), DATEPART(YEAR, t.dtdate)
```

Some sample data and a breakout of dates for a day (I picked either 2 or 4 clockin/clockouts in case someone didn't take a break.  Here is the output:

```
FirstName   LastName    LogDate     TimeIn    BreakOut  BreakIn   TimeOut
Fred        Nerfherder  07/01/2014  08:00:00  12:00:00  13:00:00  18:00:00  
Fred        Nerfherder  07/02/2014  07:30:00  12:00:00  13:00:00  17:00:00  
Jaime       Craig       07/01/2014  08:00:00  12:00:00  13:00:00  17:00:00  
Janet       Weiss       07/01/2014  08:00:00  NULL      NULL      17:00:00  
Janet       Weiss       07/02/2014  08:00:00  12:30:00  14:00:00  16:30:00
```

Comment: Sir Kevin thank you...this works really fine :)